Where can I find the V2 API URLs for the US Department of Labor's API?
On developer.dol.gov only API V1 URLs are documented. How can I translate them from V1 to V2?

According to that link, the new API will be launched in "Summer of 2024", which could be as late as August.

I think it would be here now:
https://dataportal.dol.gov
You can also see if data.gov will work for you:
https://catalog.data.gov/organization/u-s-department-of-labor-bureau-of-labor-statistics
